# Prevent call to inherited method in subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a subclass of `UIView`, that have inherited the `- initWithFrame:` method. However, I don't want that method to be called on my subclass.
Is there any way to "delete" that method on my subclass?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't implement it and don't call `[super initWithFrame:aRect]`. Just call [`doesNotRecognizeSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-doesNotRecognizeSelector_) with the `_cmd` argument:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect
{
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
}
```

If the method does not return `void`, you will receive a warning from the compiler:

> Control reaches end of non-void function.

To "remove" this warning, add `return self;` (in this case) as the last line to make the compiler happy. It will never be reached at runtime because `doesNotRecognizeSelector:` raises a `NSInvalidArgumentException` exception.

Comment: This produces me a warning "Control reaches end of non-void function". Is there any way for delete that warning?